# Prove or disprove the statement: For all real numbers $x,y$, $⌊xy⌋=⌊x⌋⌈y⌉$. What's wrong with my counter example?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Prove or disprove the statement: For all real numbers $x,y$, $⌊xy⌋=⌊x⌋⌈y⌉$.

I used the counter example $x = 1.9$, $y = 1.9$.

$⌊1.9 \cdot 1.9⌋ =  3$

$⌊1.9⌋⌈1.9⌉ = (1)(2) = 2$

But the professor said that this statement was actually true and I got 0 marks. Does anyone know what was wrong with my counter example?

Comment: "4. 0/3.  The statement is true, and can be proved." This was from an online course, I just wanted to verify before I said something and looked stupid.

Comment: That statement does not provide an answer to the question. You have provided a valid counterexample and hence shown it cannot be proved.

Comment: It's possible that instead of the ceiling of y he meant the floor of y. Everything looks right on my end so I'm going to send him an email.

Comment: It still wouldn't be true. The same counterexample would give$$3=1\cdot1$$

Comment: What exactly was the question?

Comment: It's exactly the question in the title with no typos.  Prove or disprove the following statement: “For all real numbers x,y, ⌊xy⌋=⌊x⌋⌈y⌉.” (3 marks).

Comment: So $x,y$ can be negative??

Comment: Ask your professor to prove the claim.

Comment: That's the only option at this point I guess.

Comment: If negative numbers are alowed then $-1/2, 2$ is an example.. The LHS is $-1$ and the RHS is $-2$.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the professor is wrong and the question is meaningless.

Answer (score 4):

The professor is clearly wrong unless the notation means something other than the floor/ceiling function or you misread the question. Double check to make sure the problem on the assignment matches what you just wrote here; then, go to office hours and ask the prof to take a look.

Answer (score 3):

Your example is true. There is nothing wrong with it.